# Какой алгоритм у поиска нужной суммы чисел из двух диапазонов?

Tags: алгоритм, математика

[image: Сама задача]

В общем простой обход и складывание каждого с каждым не подходит. Работает медленно. Не могу придумать что то более оптимальное

Comment: Нет ничего *более* оптимального. Какой смысл вкладывается в слово "диапазон"?

Comment: код то где ваш?

Comment: Что мешало приложить условие в виде текста, а не картинки?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например, так:

```
bool solution(int l1, int r1, int l2, int r2, int s,
              int&s1min, int&s1max, int&s2min, int&s2max)
{
    if (s < l1+l2) return false;
    if (s > r1+r2) return false;

    s1min = s - r2; if (s1min < l1) s1min = l1;
    s2min = s - r1; if (s2min < l2) s2min = l2;

    s1max = s - l2; if (s1max > r1) s1max = r1;
    s2max = s - l1; if (s2max > r2) s2max = r2;

    return true;
}


int main()
{
    int l1, r1, l2, r2, s, s1m, s1M, s2m, s2M;
    cin >> l1 >> r1 >> l2 >> r2 >> s;
    if (!solution(l1,r1,l2,r2,s,s1m,s1M,s2m,s2M))
        cout << "No solution\n";
    else
    {
        cout << s1m << " <= s1 <= " << s1M << endl;
        cout << s2m << " <= s2 <= " << s2M << endl;
    }
}
```

Вы получаете возможные диапазоны значений `s1` и `s2` - выбирайте, какое значение вам подходит :)

Надеюсь, из кода идея понятна?

Comment: Да. Всё понятно. Спасибо